# Proper way to fire multiple HttpWebRequest that might take a long time

Tags: c#, multithreading, httprequest, task

In my application I have a text area where the user may enter several urls (usually a number around 1000).

For each url, I fire a http request this way:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

**Problem:**
Quite often the url server is offline, which means `request.GetResponse()` will hang for `request.Timeout` milliseconds.
I need the system **to not stand around waiting for the timeout**; instead, I want to use the spare time to fire the remaining requests while a certain request is waiting for a response.

**My Solution**
I though about dispatching each request in a different task
My solution, therefore, looks like this:

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[numberOfUrls];
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfUrls; ++i)
{
    int index = i;
    tasks[index] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Request(urls[index]));
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

**Question: what is the proper way to do solve this problem?**

I'm not sure my way is the proper way because after reading a lot of material about the whole C# async/multithread/parallel mechanism (which I'm not very familiarized with) I got really confused.
At this point I'm not sure I'm doing this asynchronously or with multiple threads or whatever.
I read suggestions that I should make the method that fire the requests **async** and them call it and **await**. But then I also found people saying that it would not take advantage of parallelism and so on.

I'm predicting people will mark this as opinion based, but I urge you to think harder because it really is not: it is about using the framework correctly based on how it works and is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 0):

What matters here is that you need to issue a certain number of HTTP requests in parallel. Always have many outstanding. This is what gains you performance here.

The technology that you use to make that happen is not important.

What I would do is use async IO for the HTTP requests and use [one of the common techniques of processing a list of items in parallel asynchronously](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/05/10278165.aspx).

You probably should use the modern `HttpClient` class which works nicely with await. But that is not strictly required.

Determine the degree of parallelism experimentally.

---

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, Func<T, Task> body) 
{ 
    return Task.WhenAll( 
        from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop) 
        select Task.Run(async delegate { 
            using (partition) 
                while (partition.MoveNext()) 
                    await body(partition.Current); 
        })); 
}
```